# Selecting site to browse in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, search, url

This code is for part of my first major contribution to open-source, for the [socli](https://github.com/gautamkrishnar/socli) project. The purpose is to allow the user to select a site from the stack exchange network to browse and fill two variables with the appropriate urls (used through the rest of the program). Since the stack exchange network is adding new sites all the time, I wanted to make it decently easy to update the stored list. Also, I'm lazy, and didn't want to manually create a dictionary =) So I use a text file with the list of sites copy-pasted into it and the code takes care of the rest.

### Approach

The purpose of the code is to go through a text file named `sites.txt` filled with urls in a format like

```
https://codereview.stackexchange.com
https://physics.stackexchange.com
```

Taking the above, it would then produce a dictionary looking like

```
{'codereview':'https://codereview.stackexchange.com', 'physics':'https://physics.stackexchange.com'}
```

It would also print

```
Sites: codereview, physics
```

and allow the user to select one of the above, storing the url and a modified version of the url in a variable. I'd like to know if I've done this in the best possible way, and also get general feedback.

### Code

```
import re
siteslst = {}
with open('sites.txt', 'r') as s:
    data = s.read()
    data = data.splitlines()
    for i in data:
        keyVal = re.search(r'(\w+)\.',str(i)).group(1)
        siteslst[str(keyVal)] = str(i)
testInput = siteslst.keys()
print('Sites: ', ', '.join(testInput), '\n')
validInput = False
while validInput == False:
    searchSite = input("which site would you like to search? ")
    if searchSite in testInput:
        url = siteslst[searchSite]
        urlSearch = siteslst[searchSite]+'/search?q='
        validInput = True
    else:
        validInput = False
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a list of things I would improve:

- variable naming - PEP8 recommends to use lower_case_with_underscores style of variable names
- instead of a regular expression, you can use [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) to parse the domain name
- you can use a *dictionary comprehension* to construct a dictionary of sites
- you don't actually need a boolean flag for your `while` loop - instead initialize an *endless loop* and break it once the input is valid
- instead of calling `.keys()` and passing the "viewkeys" result to `str.join()` - you can pass your dictionary directly

Improved code:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse


with open('sites.txt') as input_file:
    sites = {
        urlparse(url).netloc.split('.')[0]: url
        for url in input_file
    }

print('Sites: ', ', '.join(sites), '\n')

while True:
    search_site = input("Which site would you like to search?\n")
    if search_site in sites:
        url_search = sites[search_site]+'/search?q='
        print(url_search)
        break
```

**Further thoughts:**

- make the code more *modular* and extract parts of the code into separate functions - at this moment, it is clear that you have 2 separate high-level things you do in the code - getting the dictionary of sites and getting the user's input
- put the execution code to under the [`if __name__ == '__main__':`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) to avoid the code to be executed on import
- you don't actually need to handle the list of sites manually - `StackExchange` provides an [API endpoint with that information](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/sites)

Comment: I changed two things - one, in the `if` statement, I removed `print(url_search)` because I don't need that, and second, I added `url = sites[search_site]`. Doing this for some reason caused it to ask the question twice. Why might that be?

Comment: @heather make sure that you definitely `break` inside the `if search_site in sites:`. Thanks.